# String manipulation/edits in Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, string

Say I have some html code:

```
<select id=something>
    <option id="4" data-email="myemail@email.com">....
```

Then I make a call later to retrieve this data-email attribute through a javascript call:

```
var $opt = $("#something option:selected");
var str = $opt.data("data-email")
```

How would I go about taking this var which is a string, and making it from

"myemail@email.com"

to

"myemail.thanksfortheedit@email.com

(I'm trying to parse the string til the @ sign, then place a string before that, and then rename the variable..

Please show me how to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try calling `explode('@', $str)` in PHP to retrieve an array with the values "myemail" and "email.com". Then concatenate them back together with the extra text required.

```
$emailParts = explode('@', $str);
$newEmail = $emailParts[0] . ".thanksfortheedit@" . $emailParts[1];
```

It's a little dirty, but it does the trick.

A similar method can be done in JavaScript with the `split()` function.

```
var emailParts = str.split('@');
var newEmail = emailParts[0] + ".thanksfortheedit@" + emailParts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

in jquery

```
var part1 = str.split ("@")[0] ;
var part2 = str.split ("@")[1];
var result = part1+"tanksforedit@"+part2;
```

In php:

```
$parts = explode ("@" , $str);
$part1 = $parts [0];
$part2 = $parts [1];
$rseult = $part1 . "thanksforedit@". $part2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with some regular expressions like the following:

```
([^@]+)@(\S+)
```

And then replace it with `$1.somethingelse@$2`, see a demo for JavaScript on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aD8jK8/1)